# How to create the interactive button in slack

Tags: python, slack-api, rasa-core

I am trying to build chatbot using Rasa-core integrating with slack, don't have any clear idea about creating a button in slack and user and bot conversation.

So if anyone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out the Slack Tutorials for starters: https://api.slack.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define buttons in the `template` section of your domain file, e.g.:

```
slots:
  game:
    type: text

templates:
    utter_ask_for_game:
    - text: "Would you like to play a game?"
      buttons:
      - title: "Chess"
        payload: '/choose{"game": "Chess"}'
      - title: "Falken's Maze"
        payload: "/choose{"game": "Falken\'s Maze"}"
      - title: "Thermonuclear War"
        payload: '/choose{"game": "Thermonuclear War"}'
```

This is the [Slack example](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) implemented as shown in the [Rasa Core docs](https://rasa.com/docs/core/slots/#slots-set-by-clicking-buttons).
It asks the user "Would you like to play a game?" and offers three buttons for three different games. Depending on which button the user selects, the intent `choose` is triggered with different slot values. Depending on whether the slot value is set you can then go down different story paths, or trigger [custom actions](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions). Note, that you might choose a different slot type, e.g. `categorical`. Using the `categorical` type, you can have different stories depending on the value of your slots.